# POST with a URL as a string gets interpreted strangely by flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a chrome extension using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) AJAX Requests. It is talking to a REST api on flask. It POSTs a URL as a string (as can be seen in the send()). Then I am trying to get the flask to save the URL as a string, but it interprets the URL very strangely. Right now I am just trying to save a local variable named "url" as a string of the URL that is posted.

Flask code:

```
for items in request.form:
      url = items
      break
 print str(request.form)
 print str(url)
```

Command Line output:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('redirect', u'true'), ('http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KHWSB5M?gwSec', u'1'), ('ref_',
 u's9_simh_gw_p74_d15_i2')])
redirect
```

Javascript/Ajax:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = text; //getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);

  };
  xhr.send("http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KHWSB5M?gwSec=1&redirect=true&ref_=s9_simh_gw_p74_d15_i2");
```

Stack overflow is changing the url in  the send function. Here it is: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KHWSB5M?gwSec=1&redirect=true&ref_=s9_simh_gw_p74_d15_i2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KHWSB5M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems, both on the client-side.

First, you are submitting a form, which should be a set of key/value pairs. If you need to send a url, what would make more sense is to use this syntax:

```
url=http://www.amazon.com/...
```

Then on the Flask side you can get this URL with:

```
url = request.form['url']
```

But before you are ready to do that you have to consider a second issue with character escaping. The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type requires that the values of the form fields are URL encoded to be properly interpreted by the server. Here is how the URL that you specified in your question would look like, when encoded:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB00KHWSB5M%3FgwSec%3D1%26redirect%3Dtrue%26ref_%3Ds9_simh_gw_p74_d15_i2
```

You can use the function [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to generate this encoding.

With the two changes I mentioned, your `send()` call would be as follows:

```
xhr.send("url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://www.amazon.com/..."));
```